# How to submit a rating and assign the new average rating to a MongoDB database using Express?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm currently working on a back-end project for my college degree, focusing on Node.JS, MongoDB and Express, and so far, it's been somewhat smooth. However, the assignment, which focuses on creating an API, requires me to crate a route that accepts a rating, that I send to the database along with a userId to make ratings unique. This is working, but the same route also requires me to calculate an average rating that is sent to a averageRating in my database. I have successfully managed to send the star rating, but I can't figure out how to assign the average rating. I'm using a function that calculates the average, and I'm trying to pass its result as an argument with updateOne(), but it's not working. Anyone knows what's the deal ? Code is below

```
exports.bookRating = (req, res) => {
  Book.findOne({ _id: req.params.id })
    .then((book) => {
      if (!book) {
        const newRating = new Book({
          userId: req.auth.userId,
          grade: req.body.rating,
        });
      } else if (req.body.rating < 1 || req.body.rating > 5) {
        throw new Error("La note n'est pas valide !");
      } else {
        const ratings = book.ratings;
        if (!ratings.find((rating) => rating.userId === req.auth.userId)) {
          const newRating = {
            id: req.params.id,
            userId: req.auth.userId,
            grade: req.body.rating,
          };
          ratings.push(newRating);
          book.save();
          const calculatedAverage = calculateAverageRating(ratings);
          Book.updateOne(
            { _id: req.params.id },
            { averageRating: calculatedAverage }
          )
            .save()
            .then(() => res.status(200).json({ book }))
            .catch((error) =>
              res.status(400).json({ error: "Echec de la moyenne" })
            );
        }
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => res.status(400).json({ error: "une autre erreur" }));
};

function calculateAverageRating(ratings) {
  let totalGrades = ratings.reduce((sum, rating) => sum + rating.grade, 0);
  return totalGrades / ratings.length;
}
```

I'm expecting the calculated average value to be assigned to the averageRating field in the database, but I'm getting a code 400 Bad Request error instead. The userId/rating pair is successfully sent to the database, though

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the .updateOne() method and then calling .save() on the result, which is not the correct way to update a single document in Mongoose. Instead, you could use the .findOneAndUpdate() method to update the existing document. Something like this should work,

```js
Book.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: req.params.id },
  { averageRating: calculatedAverage },
  { new: true } // This option returns the updated document
)
.then((updatedBook) => {
  res.status(200).json({ book: updatedBook })
})
.catch((error) =>
  res.status(400).json({ error: "Echec de la moyenne" })
)
```